# Usage of "for which" P(x,y) is false during quantification of two variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There's a little confusion between the usage of "for which" in my discrete mathematics explaination. I do need a little help to break down this connective.

For instance :

```
Statament : [Universal(x)Universal(y)P(x,y)]
When True : P(x,y) is true for every pair x,y
```

This makes sense because after all universal stand for everything. So therefore, P(x,y) is true for every single pair of x,y if the statament is true

However when it is false, it seems a little odd

```
When False : There is a pair x,y for which P(x,y) is false
```

What do they exactly mean?

Am i right to assume that, the above statement is false if and only if P(x,y) is false for just 1 pair of x,y only?

Then why do the author not write it in a simple way. I believe there's many misunderstanding with the word "for which" in mathematics or am i even getting the reason wrong for the false statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following statements (about *real numbers* $x,y$):

Let $P_1(x,y)$ represent "$x^2+y^2\ge 0,$" let "$P_2(x,y)$" represent" $x^2+y^2>0,$" let $P_3(x,y)$ represent "$\lvert x^2-y^2\rvert>0$," and let $P_4(x,y)$ represent "$\lvert x^2-y^2\rvert<0.$"

Now, the claim $\forall x,\forall y,P_1(x,y)$ is true. The claim $\forall x,\forall y,P_2(x,y)$ is false, and the *only* pair of real numbers for which $P(x,y)$ is false is the pair $(x,y)=(0,0).$ The claim $\forall x,\forall y,P_3(x,y)$ is also false, but there are *infinitely many* pairs $(x,y)$ for which $P_3(x,y)$ is false (namely, whenever $x=y$ or $x=-y$). There are literally *no* pairs $(x,y)$ for which $P_4(x,y)$ is true, so the claim $\forall x,\forall y,P_4(x,y)$ is false, as well.

To sum up, a universal claim fails whenever there is *at least* one counterexample, but it may be that there are many (or *all*) counterexamples.

P.S.: Another (probably more common) phrase that is often used is "such that." It means the same thing as "for which."

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not right to assume that. The statement is false if there is a pair (x,y) such that P(x,y) is false

This pair needs not to be unique !

And I don't see what's your problem with "for which"

Comment: i'm a little confused for the connective such that and for which. is there any simpler way of explaining that?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan : You have a pair (x,y) and for this pair, P(x,y) is false